# how to encrypt model property in mvc5?

Tags: c#, linq, encryption, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing one mvc5 application with jquery. I am writing linq queries to access data from database. For example if i have the following model

```
public class employee
{
public string fname{get;set;}
public string lname{get;set;}
}
```

If i write below linq query to fetch data

```
 var data=(from c in db.employee select c).to list();
```

For example i will get 3 rows of data as below.

```
fname    lname
mike     job
steve    wagh
james    anderson
```

In the above process i will pass data to view. If i want to have fname or lname in the encrypted format then how can I do these? Is there any way to convert it? I written class to encrypt a string with method called encrypt which takes one parameter. May i get some idea to achieve this. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in your linq query as well like this

```
var data=(from c in db.employee select new Employee{ lname = encrypt(lname), fname = encrypt(fname)}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. For example if i have one complex query as below  var data = table.GroupBy(x => x.upld_id).Select(x => new GroupVM1
                {
                    upload_document_id = x.Key,
                    Items = x
                }).ToList();  Then inside Items i have one property called id then how can i encrypt it?

Comment: You can do it like this
`var data = table.GroupBy(x => x.upld_id).Select(x => new GroupVM1 { upload_document_id = x.Key, Items = x.Select(i => new Items{Id=i.Id, lname = encrypt(i.lname)}) }).ToList();`